# Translate .ecw to .tif with GDAL from OSGeo in Python

Tags: python, gdal, translate, osgeo

I have about 250 .ecw files I want to transform to .tif or .png or .jpg using GDAL and Python. This is my code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
inputfile = gdal.Open('C:/Users/Berteld/aGIS/python/data/wms/orthophotos_2019/dop20rgb_400_5826_2_be_2019.ecw')
outputfile = 'C:/Users/Berteld/aGIS/python/data/wms/orthophotos_2019/dop20rgb_400_5826_2_be_2019.jpg'

gdal.Translate(inputfile, outputfile)
```

This results in

```
ERROR 4: `C:/Users/Berteld/aGIS/python/data/wms/orthophotos_2019/dop20rgb_400_5826_2_be_2019.ecw' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

When using the OSGeo4W Shell it works like a charm, but I don't want to do this by hand for all of the files. These are my environment variables:

```
GDAL_DATA = C:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal 
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH = C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: curious, have you found the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not!

Answer (score 0):

I think these two steps will help you:

1. install *gdal-ecw* package ( `pip install gdal-ecw` )
2. swap the parameters in gdal.Translate, the correct syntax is
   `gdal.Translate(outputfile, inputfile)`